# Apache POI not applying certain color indices

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, styling

Java 8 and Apache POI 4.1.x here. I have some Java code that writes a list of objects to an Excel file and its working *perfectly* fine, with the exception of some color-based cell styles I'm trying to apply:

```
public void applyPriceListDataCellStyle(PriceListItem priceListItem, Cell cell) {

    short colorIndex;
    switch(priceListItem.getChangeType()) {
        case ADDITION:
            colorIndex = IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex();
            break;
        case DELETION:
            XSSFColor purple = new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(120,81,169), new DefaultIndexedColorMap());
            colorIndex = purple.getIndex();
            break;
        case PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_INCREASE:
            colorIndex = IndexedColors.RED.getIndex();
            break;
        case PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_DECREASE:
            colorIndex = IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex();
            break;
        default:
            // NO_CHANGE (leave unstyled)
            colorIndex = IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex();
            break;
    }

    Map<String,Object> cellProps = new HashMap<>();
    cellProps.put(CellUtil.FILL_FOREGROUND_COLOR, colorIndex);
    cellProps.put(CellUtil.FILL_PATTERN, FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

    CellUtil.setCellStyleProperties(cell, cellProps);

}
```

Above, the `applyPriceListDataCellStyle` method is called *after* a `Cell` is created from a `Row` object. The `cell` instance is then passed into this method as an argument, along with my `PriceListItem` bean (which is the data I'm writing to each row in the Excel file).

The `PriceListItem` bean has a `ChangeType` property (enum) that dictates what color the cell should appear as in the final Excel file.

At runtime, I am calling this method on the cells of 5 different rows (so 5 different `PriceListItems`) of each `ChangeType` value, and I get output that looks like:

[image]

So:

- The 1st row, which is a "`NO_CHANGE`" (which maps to `IndexedColors.WHITE`) works perfectly fine, as expected
- The 2nd row, which is an "`ADDITION`" (which maps to `IndexedColors.YELLOW`) works perfectly fine, as expected
- The 3rd row, which is a "`DELETION`" (which maps to my custom `purple` color) **appears jet black instead -- wrong!**
- The 4th row, which is a "`PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_INCREASE`" (which maps to `IndexedColors.RED`) **appears gray -- wrong!**
- The 5th row, which is a "`PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_DECREASE`" (which maps to `IndexedColors.GREEN`) **appears a lighter shade of gray -- wrong!**

**Where am I going awry on setting the colors on the cells of these various rows?**

Comment: The `CellUtil` only works using `org.apache.poi.ss.*`. It cannot work using a `XSSFColor`. It only works using `IndexedColors`. Hence the black color, because `purple.getIndex()` returns `0`. But the other wrong cases are not reproducible without having a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter (+1) - here's [something I just cobbled together](https://github.com/bitbythecron/hello-windows/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/windows/hello/PoiColors.java), if you run that code it gives you the [`acme.xlsx`](https://github.com/bitbythecron/hello-windows/blob/master/acme.xlsx). Interesting GREEN is now working, but RED still isn't. So I guess at this point I'm still looking for solutions for RED and PURPLE. With PURPLE I tried creating a custom one but as you said it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apache poi` [CellUtil](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html) only works using `org.apache.poi.ss.*`. It cannot work using a `XSSFColor` because `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle` has no method to get/set fill foreground color from a `XSSFColor`. It only works using `short` color indexes from [IndexedColors](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/IndexedColors.html). Hence the black color, because in your code `purple.getIndex()` always returns `0`. So if `CellUtil` shall be used, which is to recommend, then choose a color from `IndexedColors` instead of creating a custom color. There is `IndexedColors.VIOLET` for example.

But the other wrong cases are not reproducible for me. The following [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) works for me as expected. It needs a `price-list-template.xlsx` having at least one worksheet.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class PoiColors {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        List<PriceListItem> priceList = new ArrayList<>();

        PriceListItem noChange = new PriceListItem();
        noChange.modelNumber = "123";
        noChange.price = BigDecimal.valueOf(1.99);
        noChange.changeType = ChangeType.NO_CHANGE;

        PriceListItem addition = new PriceListItem();
        addition.modelNumber = "456";
        addition.price = BigDecimal.valueOf(2.99);
        addition.changeType = ChangeType.ADDITION;

        PriceListItem deletion = new PriceListItem();
        deletion.modelNumber = "789";
        deletion.price = BigDecimal.valueOf(3.99);
        deletion.changeType = ChangeType.DELETION;

        PriceListItem increase = new PriceListItem();
        increase.modelNumber = "234";
        increase.price = BigDecimal.valueOf(4.99);
        increase.changeType = ChangeType.PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_INCREASE;

        PriceListItem decrease = new PriceListItem();
        decrease.modelNumber = "345";
        decrease.price = BigDecimal.valueOf(5.99);
        decrease.changeType = ChangeType.PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_DECREASE;

        priceList.add(noChange);
        priceList.add(addition);
        priceList.add(deletion);
        priceList.add(increase);
        priceList.add(decrease);

        new PoiColors().exportPriceList(priceList, "acme.xlsx");

    }

    private void exportPriceList(
            List<PriceListItem> priceList,
            String targetAbsPath) throws IOException {

        // set variables based on specified format
        String templateName = "price-list-template.xlsx";

        // load the template
        InputStream inp = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(templateName).openStream();
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        workbook.setSheetName(workbook.getSheetIndex(sheet), "ACME");

        // plug in the header/metadata info and format some headers so they get autosized properly
        Row row2 = CellUtil.getRow(1, sheet);
        Cell c2 = CellUtil.getCell(row2, 2);
        c2.setCellValue("ACME");


        // create the data rows and apply styling
        // start at row #11 which is where data rows begin
        int rowNum = 11;

        // rip through the items and write them to the rows; apply styling as appropriate
        for (PriceListItem priceListItem : priceList) {

            Row nextRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum);

            Cell changeType = nextRow.createCell(0);
            changeType.setCellValue(priceListItem.changeType.name());
            applyPriceListDataCellStyle(priceListItem, changeType);

            Cell modelNumber = nextRow.createCell(1);
            modelNumber.setCellValue(priceListItem.modelNumber);
            applyPriceListDataCellStyle(priceListItem, modelNumber);

            Cell price = nextRow.createCell(2);
            price.setCellValue(priceListItem.price.doubleValue());
            applyPriceListDataCellStyle(priceListItem, price);

            rowNum++;

        }

        // resize the columns appropriately
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(c);
        }


        // export to file system
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(targetAbsPath);
        workbook.write(fos);

        fos.close();
        inp.close();
        workbook.close();

    }

    private void applyPriceListDataCellStyle(PriceListItem priceListItem, Cell cell) {

        short colorIndex;
        switch(priceListItem.changeType) {
            case ADDITION:
                colorIndex = IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex();
                break;
            case DELETION:
                colorIndex = IndexedColors.VIOLET.getIndex();
                break;
            case PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_INCREASE:
                colorIndex = IndexedColors.RED.getIndex();
                break;
            case PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_DECREASE:
                colorIndex = IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex();
                break;
            default:
                // NO_CHANGE (leave unstyled)
                colorIndex = IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex();
                break;
        }

        Map<String,Object> cellProps = new HashMap<>();
        cellProps.put(CellUtil.FILL_FOREGROUND_COLOR, colorIndex);
        cellProps.put(CellUtil.FILL_PATTERN, FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        CellUtil.setCellStyleProperties(cell, cellProps);

    }

}

class PriceListItem {
    public String modelNumber;
    public BigDecimal price;
    public ChangeType changeType;
}

enum ChangeType {
    NO_CHANGE,
    ADDITION,
    DELETION,
    PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_INCREASE,
    PRICE_ADJUSTMENT_DECREASE
}
```

Result is `acme.xlsx` which looks like so:

[image]

---

Using `IndexedColors` the colors are set in `Office Open XML` `/xl/styles.xml` as follows:

```
...
<fill>
 <patternFill patternType="solid">
  <fgColor indexed="13"/>
  <bgColor indexed="64"/>
 </patternFill>
</fill>
...
```

The indexed colors are not given by `RGB` but are taken from the default color palette. If you have the suspicion that your spreadsheet calculation application uses a different default color palette than `Excel`, then you can test this using the following code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestIndexedColors {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String templateName = "price-list-template.xlsx";
        InputStream inp = TestIndexedColors.class.getClassLoader().getResource(templateName).openStream();
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Row row; Cell cell; int r = 11;
        Map<String,Object> cellProps;
        for (IndexedColors color : IndexedColors.values()) {
            row = sheet.createRow(r++);
            cell = row.createCell(0); cell.setCellValue(color.getIndex());
            cell = row.createCell(1); cell.setCellValue(color.name());
            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cellProps = new HashMap<>();
            cellProps.put(CellUtil.FILL_FOREGROUND_COLOR, color.getIndex());
            cellProps.put(CellUtil.FILL_PATTERN, FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            CellUtil.setCellStyleProperties(cell, cellProps);
        }

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("acme.xlsx"); 
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        workbook.close();
    }
}
```

It needs a `price-list-template.xlsx` having at least one worksheet. The result `acme.xlsx` shows indexes, names and colors of all possible indexed colors using the current default color palette.

Comment: Thanks @Axel (+1 again) -- it might be important to note that I'm on a Mac and creating a `price-list-template.numbers` file in the Mac OS "Numbers" (Excel wannabe) program, and then exporting that file as `price-list-template.xlsx`. I'm wondering if Numbers somehow screws things up for the RED color when generating the template for my Java/POI app to use?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup: Maybe `Numbers` uses a different default color palette than `Excel`. See my supplements for how to check.

Comment: I am giving you the green check but just FYI the solution for my "red problem" was...I have to specify `IndexedColors.RED1` (not `RED`)! I'm guessing `RED1` was built to address similar problems. If you know the history behind it, I'd love to know why RED1 exists...but regardless...RED1 works for me! Thanks again for all your help!