# Apache POI - issue with cell background color

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to color an Excel cell with blue color :

```
HSSFCellStyle headerCellStyle = worksheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
headerCellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.BLUE.index);
headerCellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.FINE_DOTS);

cell = rowHeader.createCell(startColIndex++);
cell.setCellValue("Titre");
cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
```

[image]

The cell should be blue instead of grey. I don't understant what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Set the cell how you want in Excel, read it back in Apache POI, and see what Excel put onto the cell style?

Comment: whatever the color of the cell is in Excel, I am getting : cell.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColor() = 64

Comment: And what's the fill foreground colour from Excel?

Comment: getFillForeground() returns : 0.  In the excel file the color of the cell is blue, without any additional texture.

Comment: See this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59311923/apache-poi-not-applying-certain-color-indices